# Convert DB2 TRANSLATE function into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I would like to convert the below DB2 query into SQL Server

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(' 11', '*', ' 0123456789') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

the above query result is `*` since the first argument matches with the values in the third argument.

What is the equivalent functionality available in the SQL server?  SQL Server has a `TRANSLATE` function, but the functionality is different.

Comment: You would be best off explaining for `TRANSLATE` in DB2 does, so that you aren't limited to those who know both dialects.

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with DB2's TRANSLATE function like me, here's a link to the documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-translate)

Comment: Not going to lie, I'm not sure that documentation actually helps me actually understand what the function does.

Comment: Heh, you're not the only one. IBM's doc style is on the cryptic side, but I figured it was a start and might prevent the question being closed before the OP adds some addition details anyway.

Comment: How does the value ' 11' equal ' 0123456789'? That makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Oh....maybe this is way to do something along the lines of regular expression?

Comment: @SeanLange the first argument starts with a space and the third argument also start with space and 0-9, so space and or 0-9 will replace with *

Comment: yes, maybe regular expression will helps, do you have a sample?

Comment: but this query SELECT TRANSLATE('00', '*', ' 0123456789') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 returns blank

Answer (score 3):

In DB2 the result of `TRANSLATE(' 11', '*', ' 0123456789')` is `*`   ([DB 2 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ce680ad5263eb0b5103c51876850bd86))

In SQL Server you need to use ([SQL Server Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30d406158f1716440a1b07d4c662bafa))

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(' 11', ' 0123456789', '*          ')
```

The DB2 version will [by default](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-translate) implicitly pad the `to-string` out with spaces to match the length of the `from_string`.

> If the length of to-string is less than the length of from-string,
> to-string is padded to the length of from-string with the pad or a
> blank

In SQL Server you need to do any such manipulation to the `to-string` before calling the function or you will get the error

> The second and third arguments of the TRANSLATE built-in function must
> contain an equal number of characters.

SQL Server has no padding logic built into the `TRANSLATE` function itself. Also the order of the 2nd and 3rd arguments is reversed between the two systems.